# Hyperlink around image in HTML, but not clickable in browser

Tags: html

**http://starterpad.com/blog/**

```
<div id="logo">
    <a href="http://starterpad.com/blog/"><img src="http://starterpad.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/copy-StarterPad-logo-new.png" height="61" width="321" alt="StarterPad Blog"></a>
</div>
```

As you can see, there's an `<a href>` tag around the `<img>` tag for the logo.  But in a browser (tried several) the logo image isn't clickable.

Any ideas why not?

Comment: Looks like there's nothing wrong with the code you posted: http://jsfiddle.net/vjs14ytr/

Comment: It's only a snippet of code from a WP site, the link is at the top of my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this WP plugin was the culprit:
**https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-bank/**

Deactivating it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

That's because the other div is on top of it. This guy

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">...</div>
```

It has something to do with the "display: table;" style set in bootstrap.min.css on line 6555.
If you turn that one property off, the div becomes smaller and stops covering the logo.

Comment: It seems that this div can be removed completely.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your div navbar is over the image so when your mouse is actually over the navbar. Add the "pull-right" class to your navbar and it should fix it.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse pull-right"></div>
```

Comment: Note that according to the [Bootstrap components page here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment), the `pull-right` alignment has been deprecated as of v3.1.0. It seems that this div can be removed completely in this instance anyway.

Comment: If you read the comment they say it's only on drop down menus: "As of v3.1.0, we've deprecated .pull-right on dropdown menus." They also say that quick floats exist in v3.1.0 which utilize the pull-right and pull-left classes: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough about Bootstrap to say for certain. So does this not technically apply?  
"Not for use in navbars. To align components in navbars with utility classes, use .navbar-left or .navbar-right instead. See the navbar docs for details." or is that for the nav items themselves?

Answer (score 0):

It's clickable as when i tried it in jsfiddle so that means some layer overlapped your a link so that it's not clickable.

Below is the layer that overlapped with your logo div.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
</div>
```

so the first fix 
is what all the above ppl have mentioned, using "pull-right" build-in class or over css with higher piority to re-align those layers to avoid overlapping.

another fix method is using z-index. 
i would suggest u add below attribute to set it to top so it's clickable

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="position: relative;z-index: 1;">
```

.........